# EF Core 2.0, Delete Single Navigation Property, one-to-one, using Fluent Api

Tags: c#, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0, cascading-deletes

Is it possible to ensure that the navigation property (child entity) is deleted when the parent entity is deleted using EF Core Fluent Api?

I have the following relation:

```
public class Estate {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public Guid AddressId {get; set;}
   public Address Address {get; set;}    
}

public class Address {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
}
```

The Address needs to be a navigation property to the Estate and I can therefore not add a foreign key on the Address to the Estate. So in this case the Address really isn't dependent on the Estate since it doesn't have a foreign key?

The behavior I am searching for is when I delete the Estate, the related Address should be deleted as well.

I have tried the following configurations without success:

1)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Estate>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Estate>(e => e.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

2)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Estate>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Estate>(e => e.AddressId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

3)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Estate>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

4)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Estate>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Is it even possible to do this without adding a relation from the Address to the Estate?
If not then I suppose the only way to delete the Address when an Estate is deleted is to do it manually (?):

```
_context.Estates.Remove(estate);
_context.Addresses.Remove(estate.Address);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be mixing *navigation properties* with *relationships*. Relationship exists regardless of the presence of a navigation property. The important is which *table* contains the FK (the corresponding entity might have explicit or shadow FK property). See [Relationships - Definition of Terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#definition-of-terms), and in particular *"**Dependent entity**: This is the entity that contains the foreign key property(s). Sometimes referred to as the 'child' of the relationship."*

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for your answer. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @IvanStoev If I understand this correct then the child in my case is the Address - in which I need to specify the FK in order to do the cascade delete. But in this case I can't add a FK on the Address to the Estate - which means, and please correct me if I am wrong, that the Address is only a navigation property on the Estate and I am therefore not able to specify a cascade delete?

Comment: The most important is to put the FK in `Address` table. You have 2 choices - make `Address` PK `Id` being also as FK (the so called "shared primary key association" which is the standard way of modelling one-to-one relationship in EF Core) or create separate FK column (with or w/o a property in the class). If you don't want navigation from `Address` to `Estate`, then don't add inverse navigation property - the relationship can fluently be configured with or w/o navigation property at each end. If you decide to take "shared PK" path, just remove `AddressId` from `Estate`  and use ...

Comment: … `modelBuilder..Entity<Estate>().HasOne(e => e.Address).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.Id);` Note that the generic type argument to `HasForeognKey` specifies the *dependent* entity.

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev - this helped me a great deal with understanding the difference between navigation properties and relations.